# Sending message with attachment in email BytesIO doesn't work - No errors shown - Python/Smtp/Email

Tags: python, email, smtp, email-attachments

I am trying to add attachment to the object created below and stored as email. It's all done within a class and this is how the class is initialised:

```
class <name>:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.msg = kwargs.get("msg", MIMEMultipart())
        self.subject = kwargs.get("subject", None)
        self.body = kwargs.get("body", None)
        self.attachment = kwargs.get("attachment", None)
```

**Attachment is not being sent**

The attachments works fine as long as the attachment is of the type `str`. Add other functionalities of adding body, subject, etc. works fine.
When I pass a `BytesIO()` type object, the mail gets sent without any errors or warnings, but the attachment is not being sent.

```
for i ,attachment in enumerate(self.attachment,start=1):
            p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            if isinstance(attachment, str):
                p.set_payload(open(attachment,"rb").read())
            else:
                p.set_payload((attachment).read())
            encoders.encode_base64(p)
            p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment", filename= f'attachment{i}.jpg')
            self.msg.attach(p)
```

**Why am I using *BytesIO()* in the first place?**

Well, I am trying to send a QR Image, which is saved using

```
qr_img.save(BytesIO(),format="png")
```

I am trying to send the image generated from `qrcode` module without saving it locally.

**Message is sent like this:**

```
self.server.send_message(msg)
```

Where `self.server` is the `smtplib.SMTP_SSL()` object.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: first you have to `buffer = BytesIO()` and later `qr_img.save(buffer, format="png")` - and now you can add `buffer.read()` or `buffer.getvalue()` as attachment. To make sure you may have to move file pointer to the beginning `buffer.seek(0)`

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. Maybe you never add it as attachment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the buffer values were not read using `.read()` method. Using the `.getvalue()` method instead worked for me.

*Note:* No errors are thrown when using `.read()`.